# VND Currency formatting

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
var x = 1000;
x = x.toLocaleString('vi', {style : 'currency', currency : 'VND'});
console.log(x);
```

I expected output is:

> 1.000đ

But the actual output is:

> đ1.000

Can anyone help me? thank a lot.

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/willsp/polyfill-Number.toLocaleString-with-Locales

Answer (score 5):

You can use format from other country as below:

```js
var x = 1000;
x = x.toLocaleString('it-IT', {style : 'currency', currency : 'VND'});
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intl.NumberFormat` [See more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat:)

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('vi-VN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'VND' }).format(1000));
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information from the link provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 1000;
x = x.toLocaleString('en-US', {style : 'currency', currency : 'VND'});
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const money = 123456789.987654321;
    const config = { style: 'currency', currency: 'VND', maximumFractionDigits: 9}
    const formated = new Intl.NumberFormat('vi-VN', config).format(money);
    console.log(formated);
```

You can use **[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)** object enables language-sensitive number formatting in a new project enviroment.

```
    const money = 123456789.987654321;
    const config = { style: 'currency', currency: 'VND', maximumFractionDigits: 9}
    const formated = new Intl.NumberFormat('vi-VN', config).format(money);
    console.log(formated);
```